# Getting Into Quant Field without Phd or Masters

Tags: quants

I was wondering it is possible to get into a quant role without a masters or a PhD. And if so, what are the steps to do so? The only resources I've really been able to find speaking to this on quantstart.com.

Just a little bit about me I am a Quantitative Economics major with a minor in Math, Stats, and Actuarial Science. I have passed two actuary exams and my senior project is on application of jump diffusion processes to  derivative pricing

Comment: Unlikely in first world places. Maybe in third world places. I find it strange that this is off-topic, but anyway Academia SE?